# Cannot restart Apache on XAMPP on MAC

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

I recently fixed a problem on my VirtualHosts on xampp, and I must restart Apache. I noticed when I stopped it through my control panel, localhost was still loading. I attempted to start it again through the control panel, and get this error:

```
XAMPP's Apache can not start while another webserver is using port 80. Please turn it off and try again.
```

So, I tried to stop any other Apache processes that could have been running using

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

through Terminal; it returned this error:

```
launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd
```

I also used

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

which returned the same error.

which I'm pretty sure is supposed to mean that Apache is already stopped. I decided to quit XAMPP and reopen it, with Apache turned off (red dot next to it). When I reopened it, Apache was already back on automatically (green dot next to it), basically it turned itself on. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm only a designer with occasional dev skills, but I do know how to fix the port issue.
In your apache config file (xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf) change the port...
Here is the text to look for...
Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

change the 80 in both listen strings to something else 91 is much less popular than 80 for system services and other apps wanting to do something through a port (of some sort)(ha ha)